# php loop based on mysql query in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hi I'm trying to update my HTML reservation sheet based on a MySQL query. I tried to use a PHP `while` loop in my JavaScript but I can't do it.
Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$date = $_GET['JOUR'];
$login = $_GET['NAME'];
require('bdd.php');
//here my query
$req = "SELECT * FROM RESERVATION WHERE resa_jour = '$date'";
//here I exec the query
$reponse = $bdd->query($req);
while ($data = $reponse->fetch())
{
    ?>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            if (<?php echo $data['id'] ?>) {
                $('.<?php echo $data['resa_salle'] . $data['resa_periode'] ?>').addClass('disable');
            }
        });
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Please ask a specific, code-based question. "I can't do it" doesn't really tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Can you provide the result html? Try to intertwine less between php and js, it's hard to read, and it'll make it hard to debug, and it'll create a lot of bugs because of that.

Comment: Alot of misunderstanding's going on here. First, your question should be more specified. And the second... I don's see any reason to use loop here.. you can just display that jQuery if your results are correct. And also ... `if (<?php echo $data['id']?>)` will be for example `if (15)` after server side scripts are executed (`if(15)` == always true).

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: It is generally best practice to minimise the intermixing of languages like this, because it can be really hard to read and debug and becomes a maintenance headache. Move as much of the PHP code out of the JS as possible; generate a JSON string with it, and then use that JSON as an object in your JS code. That'll mean you only have one line of PHP in the JS code, and the rest can be debugged as pure JavaScript. Much much easier.

Comment: Sorry it's my first time doing javascript and posting on stackoverflow, I have an Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the bad idea. You should pass only result in a JS variable and then first saw that in which format that is JSON or ARRAY. Then run a loop in as

```
$.each(data, function(index, value){
-- your code here -- 
});
```

JS and add class in that way.

Comment: Ok so I first make my query then redirect the result in a JS variable so I can run the loop on it ?

Comment: @PierreC. exactly. Just echo the PHP result variable in a JS variable and use that variable.

Comment: @PierreC. Please UPVOTE the answer if it helped you and for others. :)

Comment: I've not enough rep :)

Comment: @PierreC. OK no problem. If somedays possible. :)